# How to populate array of objects to table based on first key value

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have an array of objects:

```
tabs = ['Sample #1', 'Sample #2', 'Sample #3'];
scorePerSample: any[] = [
    {
      sampleNo: 0,
      score: 1,
    },
    {
      sampleNo: 2,
      score: 10,
    },
    {
      sampleNo: 1,
      score: 3,
    },
  ];
```

Now I want this to display in the table, and this is my html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="scoreTable">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Sample</th>
            <th scope="col">Decision Score</th>
            <th scope="col">Disposition Per Sample</th>
            <th scope="col" class="d-none">Disposition Score</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let idx = index">
            <td>{{ tab }}</td>
            <td>{{ scorePerSample }}</td>
            <td>{{ dispositionPerSample }}</td>
            <td class="d-none">{{ dispositionScore }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in the `scorePerSample`, the `score` should be displayed based on `sampleNo`. In the `dispositionPerSample` column, the data is based on the `scorePerSample`. If the score is more than 2, `dispositionPerSample` should be `Reject` otherwise `Good`. The `dispositionScore` is also based on the `dispositionPerSample`, if the `dispositionPerSample` is `Reject`, the `dispositionScore` is `1` otherwise `0`

This is my code sor far: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mjdzx6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the index value to find your score. But your two arrays must   match the good values at the same array index.

[image]

Comment: ```Sample #``` score is based on the ```sampleNo``` key. As you can see the 2nd index has a ```sampleNo``` 2 so it should be placed in ```Sample #3```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="scoreTable" border="1">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Sample</th>
            <th scope="col">Decision Score</th>
            <th scope="col">Disposition Per Sample</th>
            <th scope="col" class="d-none">Disposition Score</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let idx = index">
            <td>{{ tab }}</td>
            <td>{{ scorePerSample[idx].score }}</td>
            <td>{{ scorePerSample[idx].score > 2 ? "Reject" : "Good" }}</td>
            <td class="d-none">{{ scorePerSample[idx].score > 2 ? "1" : "0" }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: ```Sample #``` score is based on the ```sampleNo``` key. As you can see the 2nd index has a ```sampleNo``` 2 so it should be placed in Sample #3